# Why not fix the search icon's vertical alignment?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Current]

With a slight CSS modification, it would look like this:

[image: Modified]

Notice the icon is now vertically aligned with the prompt. Also, this behavior would be uniform across Mac and Windows, Chrome and Firefox.

CSS changes:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: I suggest you to use [Freehand Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/237701).

Comment: While your modified image *might* be geometrically centred, your eyes and brain might *not* perceive it to be so. This is an issue which leads to [overshooting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306061/why-do-the-subscript-numbers-look-misaligned) text in typography.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Matsmath my brain perceives it as so

Comment: Are you really asking a "Why not" discussion question or are you reporting a bug?

Comment: @TylerH I'm equally confused :S

Comment: I never noticed this until now.. Now I'm going to see it every time I use the search box :-(

Comment: Not positioning things correctly *is* a bug.

Comment: I cannot unsee it now. Thanks a lot! >: |

Comment: Your suggestion is at least [one `px` too high](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVBz.png). If the placeholder text contained letters like “g” or “p”, it would also be visually too high.

Comment: It's not "not aligned", it's a new design trend which icons and logos are lower than text. :-)

Comment: I've never noticed it before. Now I'm having tickles on it.

Comment: @Will http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/322196/revisions this will answer your question.

Comment: Careful, I hear a giant S is coming your way to beat you in the head.

Comment: The position of the icon is clearly referring to early detective movies where the detective searching for clues would actually be looking at the ground through a magnifying glass.

Comment: The O part is aligned with the bottom of the text (almost).  The handle descends.  As if it was the letter lower-case q.

Comment: @paradite Can you please update the title? The *Why not* looks weird to me (it suggests they decided not to do it) and there's not question mark.

Comment: Do we need the icon AND the text "Search Q& A"?

Comment: Isn't this just the implementation of gravity into CSS? Objects like a magnifying glass now render with improved scientific accuracy.

Comment: Such a tiny thing, so many votes, yet so unlikely to change.

Comment: I think it looks better with -91 than -92. But anway, you could modify the image too. ;)

Comment: It's a delightful bit of free-hand artfulness in an overly-correct world. Roosevelt's unpublished Fifth Freedom was "Freedom from excessive focus on alignment and margins and sh*t like that". LEAVE THE SEARCH ICON ALONE!!!!! :-)

Comment: I'm pleased that this is the worst thing we can find to complain about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has been corrected. This will be updated with the next production build. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Looks like the live site is already fixed as of now.

Comment: Hmm - The search box seems to have become a bit bigger now, and has a light gray background, was that intentional ? I think it looks slightly ugly.

Comment: @JonasCz It was intentional. The background is slightly dimmed since it's up in the right corner and not a primary action for most pages. When you focus on the search box, it turns full white though.

Answer (score 45):

How about removing the CSS background and using one of the Unicode magnifiying glasses in the placeholder:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder=" Search Q&A" style="width: 188px;">
```

Advantage. Less code, less CSS, also auto-hides the icon once you start typing which leaves more space for typing.

Comment: Disadvantage: Doesn't render correctly on Chrome on Linux (apparently): http://i.stack.imgur.com/kl7vP.png (Using a pretty uncustomized install.)

Comment: And the unicode causes the placeholder to appear awkwardly low in the input box. Normal text appears neatly vertical aligned though.

Comment: ^ The difference: http://i.imgur.com/c4zzlR6.png

Comment: As for Linux. That's a bug in Chrome or Linux which will get fixed otherwise Linux will be left behind as the rest of the internet moves on using emoji everywhere. As for awkwardly low, to me your non-emoji example is awkwardly high with double the space below the characters as above. I think you'll also find that every OS/browser combination is different with or without the emoji. [Here's a few quick tests](http://i.imgur.com/Wy1Nobn.png)

Comment: This does not properly render for me either (I suspect that this have to do with not having latest version of Microsoft Windows ©, rather then specific browser). According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12036038/1643723, the same thing can be accomplished with other, less obscure symbols, such as [⌕](http://graphemica.com/%E2%8C%95). And personally I'd use a webfont to prevent unexpected rendering depending on whatever is installed on user's system.

Comment: Very likely that these render problems are all due to font support of the glyph. And unless there is a font that works across browsers/OS combinations I don't think it would be a good choice for SE to implement.

Comment: Broke in ubuntu firefox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9HwHw.png, broke in chrome as well. So this is not a chrome bug or anything. *"otherwise Linux will be left behind"* - wtf? there are other ways to align something properly that works in all platforms. You can't put stuff like this in production.

Comment: I'd rather have a misaligned search icon than   misaligned very weird things that doesn't make sense...

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 16.04 with Chrome 51.

Comment: Go the whole hog, and use `<input type="search" ...>`

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl well, there is https://icomoon.io/.
Icons like fonts, and they work in all OS and browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I confirm it works ok with Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64) too. Perhaps you meant Chromium (which I haven't tried)?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Nope. I'm using Chrome (not Chromium) on Linux Mint 17.3. But I just tried Chromium and Firefox, didn't work in either of those, either, so probably OS rather than browser.

Comment: @Shahbaz it's broke in Ubuntu 14.04.4 firefox and chrome.

Comment: -1 Conclusion: it's a terrible idea as it doesn't work correctly in a large number of browsers + OS combinations, so please downvote.